# Do I really need a specific headset to get the benefit of Super Wideband Audio?

Tags: audio, skype, codec

Back in 2003 Skype released their [Super Wideband Audio codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILK) which was supposed to be a lot better than all other audio codecs. (better sound less bandwidth.) And they give it away with a royalty free license. So Logitech started making headsets to support it, and Valve added it to the steam friends voice chat and TF2 voice chat.

I can't find it listed as a feature on headsets or sound cards from other brands. Do they support it? Aren't audio codecs just software? Do I really need to buy a specific headset to make use of this codec? and if so, why aren't more manufacturers supporting this codec?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really need to buy a specific headset to make use of this codec?

#### You don't need a new headset!

As you said, a codec is just there to transcode audio and decode it back to an uncompressed form. What this codec might do better than others is get better quality at a given bit rate. Not more, not less.

Given that human speech [only uses a tiny bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency) of the audible frequency range (300 Hz to 3 kHz), but even the cheapest headphones support frequencies from below 100 Hz to 18 or even 20 kHz, you will most probably not hear a difference at all.

The only point here is that the software or the system you connect the headset to needs to support encoding/decoding with this codec.

<sub>Note: There **might** be a need to buy a new headphone/headset if the included microphone is cheap and of bad quality, because otherwise you can't make use of a good codec anyway. Maybe that's what the Logitech headset does. But apart from that, it's marketing, I guess.</sub>